# Table of contents for thesis

Tags: table-of-contents

I am writing my thesis and will prefer my table of contents to appear like Table Of Contents centered and not Contents aligned to the left. If U use `\tableofcontents` it appears to the left.

The other question is how do I take away chapters from my table of content so that it appears like this

```
                        Table of Contents
Chapter
1 General information
  1.1 data
  1.2 good
2 Background
  2.1 yes
  2.2 hello
```

in that other
can any body come to aid?
thanks

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.StackExchange](http://tex.stackexchange.com). You should ask one question at time so it is easier for other with the same problem to find it.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please provide a bit more information about the setup of your document. E.g., which document class do you use? And, do you load any LaTeX packages that affect the look of the table of contents, i.e., what's produced by the `\tableofcontents` command?

Comment: Please also clarify the intended look of the body of the ToC: Do you want to suppress all page numbers (which would normally be shown at the right-hand end of each row)?

Answer (score 4):

I recommend you take a look at the [tocloft](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/tocloft) package. It provides lots of commands to modify the table of contents (and the list of figures, the list of tables, and similar lists).

The following MWE illustrates the usage of the package, using some of the criteria outlined in your posting:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand\contentsname{Table of Contents}
\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\hfill\large\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftaftertoctitle}{\hfill}
\renewcommand\cftchapfont{\mdseries} % default: \bfseries
\cftpagenumbersoff{chapter} % suppress mention of page numbers for chapters, etc
\cftpagenumbersoff{section}
\cftpagenumbersoff{subsection}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect{\mdseries Chapter\par}} % insert the "Chapter" header line
\chapter{General information}
\section{Data}
\section{Good}
\chapter{Background}
\section{Yes}
\section{No}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: omg, whats with that background color?

Comment: @canaaerus: I have no idea what's going on: When I view the image in a chrome browser window (or in a safari window on my iPad) the background is plain (i.e., white, transparent), as I intend it to be. However, when I view it in an IE browser window the background is a soft baby-blue... I have no idea what may be causing this oddity.

Comment: @mico It's also blue in FF 13 on a Mac.

Comment: Strangely in `gimp` it is white too, but the _image properties_ show under _color profile_: `Lenovo ThinkPad, LCD Monitor, Lenovo ThinkPad LCD Monitor, Copyright (c) 2005 Lenovo Corporation, WhitePoint : D65 (daylight)`. Maybe some libs are acting on this _WhitePoint_ and adjust the color?!?

Comment: @canaaerus -- thanks for providing the pointer about the whitepoint profile being embedded. I've changed the save .png settings to exclude any embedding of color profiles. Hopefully this will do the trick.

Comment: @chris - I'm glad you found my suggestions helpful. Don't forget to upvote and/or accept answers you like. :-)